# How to filter those data by column number?

Tags: bash, grep

Below is part of my data.

```
......
  CN= 1 SBSDRYTGT     17146      H     17144      O  1.066
  CN= 2 SBSDRYTGT     17145      H     17144      O  1.130     13034      O  1.489
  CN= 4 SBSDRYTGT      7308     AL     17144      O  2.034     10965      O  1.764     10385      O  1.728      8896      O  1.791
  CN= 1 SBSDRYTGT     17146      H     17144      O  1.086
  CN= 1 SBSDRYTGT     17145      H     17144      O  1.039
  CN= 4 SBSDRYTGT      7308     AL     17144      O  2.039     10965      O  1.757     10385      O  1.730      8896      O  1.758
  CN= 1 SBSDRYTGT     17146      H     17144      O  1.069
  CN= 1 SBSDRYTGT     17145      H     17144      O  1.023
  CN= 4 SBSDRYTGT      7308     AL     17144      O  2.055     10965      O  1.790     10385      O  1.715      8896      O  1.825
  CN= 1 SBSDRYTGT     17146      H     17144      O  1.092
  CN= 1 SBSDRYTGT     17145      H     17144      O  1.046
  CN= 4 SBSDRYTGT      7308     AL     17144      O  2.035     10965      O  1.770     10385      O  1.701      8896      O  1.799
  CN= 1 SBSDRYTGT     17146      H     17144      O  1.103
  CN= 1 SBSDRYTGT     17145      H     17144      O  1.058
  CN= 4 SBSDRYTGT      7308     AL     17144      O  2.037     10965      O  1.783     10385      O  1.750      8896      O  1.797
......
```

I want to show data with column number equal 11,like

```
CN= 2 SBSDRYTGT     17145      H     17144      O  1.130     13034      O  1.489
```

NOTE: please do not use any values in the columns because these values may be different. I only need data with column number equal 11.
Any further help and suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script prints all rows having exactly 11 columns:

```
awk NF==11 yourfile
```

To print all lines having strictly more than 11 columns use

```
awk 'NF>11' yourfile
```

and to print all lines having strictly less than 11 columns use

```
awk 'NF<11' yourfile
```